# IBM DataStage Designer window is hidden

Tags: window, hidden, datastage

I am working in DataStage designer. When I try to open a hash file or a Transformer in my canvas, it opens but is somehow hidden somewhere, therefore not visible.
It is not in another screen of my laptop. I literally cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug when you change your monitor configuration. After opening whatever window you were trying press ALT+SPACE. The window control dialog box for the hidden window will pop up on your screen like below.
[image]

Now just select move, press an arrow key and move your mouse. The window should pop back into your active screen attached to your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but I tried this method one thousand time. This happened also with my Oracle SQL Developer but it worked with the ALT+space and I was able to get my window back. I tried to do this in every part of the screen but the "Move" option does not appear for the window selected.
Do you know by chance if there is another method? I tried also with the registry editor (delete the folders related to DS Designer) but is still there.

Thank you in the meantime for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Windows logo key` + `Shift` + `Left Arrow` or `Right Arrow` to move a window from one monitor to another.